# Android AsyncTask with Input and Output not working

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have 2 Classes: a Main Class handling the UI and a second Class for retrieving Data from `SQL Server` by using PHP.

From the first class a mehtod in the second class is called with passing and retrieving variables. 
Actually it is working fine without `AsyncTask`.

But since I want to use the code on devices running Android 3.0 and above, I need to change the method to be an AsyncTask. Else I get this error: "`android.os.networkonmainthreadexception`"

the actual working code Looks like this:

Main class:

```
...
String inputString="1";
String outputString;
outputString = Class2.SomeMethodInClass2(inputString);   
....
```

Class2:

```
public class Class2 {

   public static String SomeMethodInClass2(String input) {
      String Output;
      ...
      //Do some php-sql stuff based on "input"-variable
      //and return the "output"-variable 
      ...
      return output;
   }
}
```

This code works perfectly on Android 2.0 but I need to change it to `AsyncTask`, because `Andoid 3.0` and above is giving me: "`android.os.networkonmainthreadexception`"

I have read a lot of threads about `AsyncTask`, but I can not get it to work with Input and Output in my code.
`Eclipse` allways tells me there is something wrong with my code.

How do I have to change my code, to be a working async Task? (please explain using my above code sample)

--edit: if there is an easier way to get rid of "`android.os.networkonmainthreadexception`" on 3.0 an above than AsyncTask, this would be fine too! --

Comment: Please post your Async Task code. Also its necessary that you do intense and time consuming operations in a separate thread - this is true for every API version not just OS 3.0 and above.

Comment: Friendly advice : Try __googling__ first or better **SO** first

Comment: Thanks, im am googling an trying since 3 days. I have a lot of asyncTask Code-Tryes, every one has different error Messages. i dont think any of them is going in the right direction

Comment: Post your code, we can help you to get rid of those errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a Callback in `SecondClass`

Extend your `SecondClass` with `Asynctask`

Implement `preExecute`,`doinbackground`, `postExecute` methods

Do your stuff in `doinbackground`
return **result** in `doinbackground`

In `postExecute` pass **result** to the `Callback`

Implement `SecondClass.Callback` in `FirstClass`
start `SecondClass` (execute) and pass a `Callback` reference from `FirstClass`

In Callback just handle your next operations with the result

EDIT :

```
public class SecondClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
public interface Callback {
    public void update(String result);
}
Callback mCallback;

    public SecondClass(Callback callback) {
        super();
    mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result = null;
        //do your stuff and save result
        return result;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(mCallback != null)
    mCallback.update(result)
        super.onPostExecute(e);
    }
}

public class FirstClass implements SecondClass.Callback{
@Override
public void update(String result){
      //do your stuff with result
}

return_type someMethod(){
  SecondClass sc = new SecondClass(this) ;
  sc.execute(someurl);
  }
  }
```

Comment: thank you, i am sure this answer is correct, but i just can't figure out how to do this to my code...

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your Posts!

But i found an alternative way that seems much easier and better to me than doing async Task.
i added to my main class:

```
public class MainClass extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
    ...
    BackgroundOperations1 ourBackgroundOperations; //<===new
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        ourBackgroundOperations = new BackgroundOperations1();  //<===new
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        ....
        ourBackgroundOperations.pause();  // <===new
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        ....
        ourBackgroundOperations.resume();  // <===new
    }




    //whole new class inside of "MainClass"
    //runs a different thread, i believe...?
    public class BackgroundOperations1 implements Runnable {
            Thread ourThread = null;
            boolean isRunning = false;



            public void pause() {
                    isRunning = false;
                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            ourThread.join();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }

            public void resume() {
                    isRunning = true;
                    ourThread = new Thread(this);
                    ourThread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (isRunning) {
                    if (dothis==true){
                        //here i call my mehtod from class2, whenever "dothis" is set to true (somewhere in my onTouch or where ever i want)
                        String inputString="1";
                        String outputString;
                        outputString = Class2.SomeMethodInClass2(inputString);

                    }   
                }
            }
    }
}
```

this works on Android 4.0 and i think it is the best way to do what i want. and to me it seems a lot clearer then AsyncTask, because i can call my methods an pass varaibles in a simple way.

or is there a reason to not do it like this?